# Display the values from select properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app where i use a `select` tag to add values in a table. With this select i can select just one value and to add it in the table.
Some of the code of select input:

```js
const searchPlayer = selectedItems => {
    selectedItems = selectedItems.map(name => name.toLowerCase());
    let arrayOfMatchedObjects = team.filter(object => {
      return selectedItems.some(selectedItem =>
        JSON.stringify(object)
          .toString()
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(selectedItem)
      );
    });
    return arrayOfMatchedObjects;
  };
```

The issue is that it doesn't work properly, because when i select a name but don't save it, and after that i change my mind and i select another name, in the table will be added both names, but i can't understand why, because in this way i add 2 names just clicking once on the button. Who knows how to solve this?  link to app: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hamilton-go4m3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your current code, you `concate` the selection in `useEffect()`, which causes the multi-selected items to been passed to the table.

Remove the `concate` method would fit your demand.

---

#### Update

Replace this

```
const addPlayer = () => {
  setnewPlayer(searchPlayer(savedPlayer));
};

useEffect(() => {
  setSavedPlayer(
    Array.from(new Set(savedPlayer.concat(selectedItems)).values())
  );
}, [selectedItems]);
```

to

```
const addPlayer = () => {
  const data = Array.from(new Set(savedPlayer.concat(selectedItems)).values());
  setnewPlayer(searchPlayer(data));
  setSavedPlayer(data);
};
```

[image]

Comment: yes, it works, but i can't add all values from select. For example, i want to add first name, and after that the second name in the table. Now i can add just one name, if i  add second the first value is changed by the second, and in result i have just one value in table. How to add the possibility to add all values in the table?

Comment: @Asking Updated, kindly check it would be appreciated

Comment: i checked, but there are an issue when delete. For example: i added both name in the table and after that i deleted them, when i will select just one name and i will save, in the table will appear all names. Could you check please?

Comment: @Asking Well this one goes much deeper, in your `Table component`, the data is been stored as `State`, but since it's been used as a `Child component`, you should use `props`, and this makes huge changes. Post a new question is preferred, and I guess this answer has solved your current problem, they are independent.